# Need help writing a script that calculates a sum indexed by fractional integers (like 1.5,2.5,3.5...)

Tags: matlab

Can someone show me how to write the following function in MATLAB

$
[
f(N) = t^{-6(N^2-1)} \sum_{j=\frac{-(N-1)}{2}}^{\frac{N-1}{2}}t^{24j^2+12j} \frac{t^{8j+2}-t^{-(8j+2)}}{(t^2-t^{-2})}
]
$

I've been trying for awhile and haven't come up with anything worth mentioning... i am BRAND NEW to programming and could really benefit from somebody showing me this I feel..

You'll notice that the sum goes from $-(n-1)/2)$ to $(n-1)/2$ where n is an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it. Use the `running_sum` quantity to compute the sum from `-(n-1)/2` to `(n-1)/2`.

You can run the function using the following command: `f = example(2,5)` where `t=2` and `N=5`.

```
function f = example(t,N)

    % compute the running sum
    running_sum = 0;
    for k = -(N-1)/2:(N-1)/2
        running_sum = running_sum + t^(24*k^2+12*k) * (t^(8*k+2)-t^(-(8*k+2)))/((t^2-t^(-2)));
    end

    % final value
    f = t^(-6*(N^2-1))*running_sum;

end
```

Comment: Thanks man, this worked great. 

I'm not trying to write a similar program and I used your code here for the blueprint. For some reason I can't get it to run. If you have any more time to help me out I'd appreciate it!!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64079677/can-somebody-help-me-get-this-matlab-coding-to-run-correctly

Comment: I'd be glad to help. Your new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64079677/can-somebody-help-me-get-this-matlab-coding-to-run-correctly was closed. Try reposting it with more details.